# Django CMS not working with uWSGI

Tags: django, nginx, wsgi

I have website developed in Django CMS.

When running it with the `manage.py runserver` it works just fine, but when I try to run it with nginx and uwsgi I get the following error:

> view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

I think it might the problem might be that I run the django cms in a `virtualenv`.

I used the same conf files for another django project but it wasn't inside an virtualenv

I start the uwsgi inside my virtualenv.

**My wsgi.ini**:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/user.name/mysite

module = mysite.wsgi

#home = /var/www/user

master = true

processes = 10

socket = /var/www/user/mysite/mysite.sock

chmod-socket = 666

vcuum = true
```

**My nginx conf**

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///var/www/user/mysite/mysite.sock;
}

server{
    # listen on port
    listen      80 default_server;
    listen      [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.name www.example.name;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server{
    #Default server?
    listen                      443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen                      [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name                 example.name www.example.name;
    charset                     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size        75M;

    ssl_certificate             /etc/letsencrypt/live/user/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/letsencrypt/live/user/privkey.pem;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location ^~ /.well-known{
        allow all;
        alias /var/www/user/.well-known;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/user/mysite/mysite/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /var/www/user/mysite/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add virtual environment path to wsgi.ini, something similar to:

```
home = /var/www/myvenv
```

But I don't know if this will solve it